# Having both [alternative heading] and no section* numbering

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I can remove section numbering by using `\section*{My Title for the Section}`.

I can provide an optional heading for `\nameref` by using `\section[Section Title]{My Title for the Section}`.

But I can't seem to combine them:

```
\section*[Section Title]{My Title for the Section}
\section[Section Title]*{My Title for the Section}
```

Both break stuff:

[image: \section*[Section Title]{My Title for the Section}]
[image: \section[Section Title]*{My Title for the Section}]

**How can I give a section an alternative heading *and* prohibit numbering?**

A minimal working example of what I want would be:

```
\section*[Section Title]{My Title for the Section}
\label{sec:title}

Referring to the \nameref{sec:title} section.
```

producing

> Referring to the *Section Title* section.

Comment: Slightly related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33696/no-section-numbers-but-still-have-pdf-bookmarks-with-hyperref/33702#33702 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17048/make-chapter-same-as-unnumbered-chapter-using-memoir

Comment: https://github.com/johannesbottcher/unnumberedtotoc/ might help

Comment: If you use a KOMA class you should look at its extra sectioning macros.

Comment: Will anything from the regular classes break if I use the KOMA class instead?

Comment: By the way, if you want all sections to be unnumbered, there is a different way.

Comment: KOMA classes are extended and feature rich alternatives to the stanard classes. There shouldn't be any problems. Some packages specially made for the standard classes are incompatible eith KOMA classes

Comment: @Johannes_B Thanks, but I only want it for this particular section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `\addcontentsline` to add the short title to ToC.

I think you could modify `\@currentlabelname` to set the short title instead of the long one.

I have also created a macro with the help of this [Werner's post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60896/101651).

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mysection}[2][\@empty]{%
    \section*{#2}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\ifx\@empty#1\relax#2\else#1\fi}
    \def\@currentlabelname{\ifx\@empty#1\relax#2\else#1\fi}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \mysection[Short title]{Long title}\label{sec:title}
    A section without number with a long title and a short one. 
    \mysection{No need short title}\label{sec:anothertitle}
    A section without number with one title only.
    \section{Normal section}
    Name reference to the short title of the first section: \nameref{sec:title}.

    Name reference
    to the title of the second section: \nameref{sec:anothertitle}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: While I did mention table of contents in my post (will edit that out now for clarity), my main purpose is to get `\nameref{sec:title}` to work properly. So good try, but no. Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: No. In your example, I want `\nameref{sec:title}` to produce "Short title".

Comment: I think this is about as good as we'll get. I'm a bit disappointed that there seems to be no easy way around this, but after looking around some I think this is one of the better ways to go at it. Thanks.

Comment: @lindhe Maybe with KOMA is easier... thank you for accepting my answer!